# Show that the right cancellation law holds in $S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $*$ be a commutative and associative binary operation
>   on a set $S$. Assume that for every $x$ and $y$ in $S$, there
>   exists $z$ in $S$ such that $x*z = y$. (This $z$ may depend
>   on $x$ and $y$.) Show that if $a, b, c$ are in $S$ and $a*c = b*c$,
>   then $a = b$.

Between $c$ and itself, there is an element $e_c$, such that $c*e_c=c$. between $c$ and $e_c$, there is an element $c^{-1}$ such that $c*c^{-1}=e_c$. Multiplying both sides of the equation  $a*c = b*c$ by $c^{-1}$, we have $a*e_c=b*e_c$. It therefore suffices to show that for any $a$ in $S$, $a*e_c=a$. Unfortunately, I don't know how to show that $e_c$ is an identity element. Notice also that if we can show $S$ is a group, then what we want to show follows trivially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is in fact an abelian group.( If we prove it is a group we have proved what you want).

Take $x$ in $S$. There is an $e$ so that $x*e=x$. We will prove for any $s$ in $s$ we have $s*e=s$. to see this write $s$ as $y*x$ (This is possible because by hypothesis given $x,s$ there is a $y$ so that $x*y=s$ but since $*$ commutes we have $y*x=e$)

Therefore $s*e=(y*x)*e=y*(x*e)=y*x=s$. Therefore $e$ acts as a right identity, and since $*$ is commutative $e$ also acts as a left identity. Therefore $(S,*,e)$ is a monoid.

On the other hand for every $x$ we have a $y$ so that $x*y=e$ and hence $y*x=e$ by commutativity of $*$. Hence every element has an inverse, so $(S,*,e)$ is an abelian group.

Comment: Why $y*e=y$? Any reason?

Comment: In what part${}$?

Comment: Woops, the first sentence was wrong. There is an $e$ so that $x*e=x$

Comment: Another error $y*x\neq e$ And in the beginning chain of expressions, you use $y*e=y$, so you're literally using what you want to prove to prove what you want to prove.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm sorry. It should be fine now. The good thing is you are paying attention.

Comment: In fact the only thing you need for the problem is for left and right multiplications by any element of $S$ to be surjective functions from $S$ to $S$. You don't need for multiplication to be commutative.

Comment: Also related is: every cancelable finite monoid is a group.

Comment: Thanks,these are very helpful!